# How to pass multiple parameter in wcf restful service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest

**IService.cs**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/IsValidUser?userid={userid}&password={password}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string IsValidUser(string userid, string password);
```

**Service.cs**

```
public string IsValidUser(string userid, string password)
{
    if (userid =="bob" && password =="bob")
    {
        return "True";
    }
    else
    {
        return "false";
    }
}
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServBehave">
        <!--Endpoint for REST-->
        <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="restPoxBehavior" contract="IService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServBehave">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <!--Behavior for the REST endpoint for Help enability-->
        <behavior name="restPoxBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Problem:**

Here my problem is that I want to pass multiple parameter while calling a WCF rest service, but I am not able to pass multiple parameters to that WCF rest service. I want to pass userid and password and check for in it. If it is bob then allow to go ahead.

And when I am calling this url:

```
http://localhost:48401/ARService/Service.svc/rest/IsValidUser?userid=bob&password=bob
```

then I am getting this error on my web page:

> Endpoint not found. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service.

If somebody have idea how to call `IsValidUser` in my case with this function parameter. Please help me.

Comment: Apart from the password transfered in plain text, you failed to mention what your actual problem is. You are not able to pass parameters? Why not? What problems did you encounter, what error messages do you get?

Comment: when i am calling this url :-http://localhost:1967/RestService/callme?id=bob&value=bob then i am getting this error :Endpoint not found. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service. on my web page.

Comment: Your url does not match your code here at all. Maybe you should make sure your service is callable first, before wondering about parameters and functions.

Comment: Your parameter names are `userid` and `password`, but you're sending `id` and `value`.

Comment: @silvermind sorry i edited my url

Comment: #nvoigt i am able to call my method but I am not able to pass parameter only.

Comment: I think there is no problem with your code, but with your service reference. You are probably missing the web.config endpoint for it. Try updating the service reference, but make sure that it's code compiles before updating.

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar I doubt this has anything todo with your function or parameters. Try inserting a function with no parameters at all, this will fail as well. Make sure the URL is correct and you have configured the endpoint correctly. Can you request the WSDL from your svc?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can write this way:

**Iservice.cs**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "IsValidUser/{userid}/{password}")]
string IsValidUser(string userid, string password);
```

**service .cs**

```
public string IsValidUser(string userid, string password)
{
   if (userid== "root" && password== "root")
   {
      return "True";
   }
   else
   {
      return "false";
   }    
}
```

Run this Url in Browser,then you will get output
**localhost/service.svc/rest/IsValidUser/root/root**

Comment: How can i pass a user ID with a domain name? like "domain\userid" I get bad request error due to "\" character in parameter.

Comment: Thank you @pankee

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "IsValidUser?userid={userid}&password={password}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string IsValidUser(string userid, string password);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Add BodyStyle on OperationContract**

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
```