# WCF REST-based service custom validation

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest

I have developed my first WCF REST based service that accepts JSon. I am fairly new to this. Everything works fine. My IService1.cs looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "balanceOutstanding")]
    List<BalOutstanding> BalanceOutstanding(Stream JSONdataStream);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "FileStatus")]
    List<FileStatus> ReturnStatus(Stream JSONdataStream);
}
```

I currently have a method that I do validation in and I call this method in **BalanceOutstanding** and **ReturnStatus** respectively. Is there another way to possibly do custom validation as maybe an entry point before it hits **BalanceOutstanding** and **ReturnStatus**?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Just a bit more detail about my custom validation. I basically add the user to a Dictionary memory object with a DateTime.Now recording the exact time the first request was made. This has a limit of 2 hours. Every subsequent request checks the Dictionary and if 2 hours have elapsed since first request, the user is re-authenticated from another server and a new DateTime is recorded.

Comment: This should help out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623432/how-to-pass-multiple-parameter-in-wcf-restful-service

~Enjoy

Comment: @DustinFalgout, this most certainly did help me.