# Calling WCF service with parameter

Tags: wcf, parameters

I am developing a SharePoint addin which has a SharePoint-hosted part and a provider-hosted part. In my provider hosted part, I have a couple of services that install a couple of things like Taxonomy and Search. I use C# CSOM for this. This is the only purpose of the provider-hosted part. When the addin is installed, a AppInstalled Event Triggers which calls a remote event receiver. This remote event receiver should then call my WCF services one by one.

Now to my actual question: I currently use this approach for consuming my services:

```
var taxBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
var taxEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(remoteUrl.ToString() + "/Services/TaxonomySetupService.svc");
var taxChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ISetupService>(taxBinding, taxEndpoint);

ISetupService taxClient = null;

try
{
    taxClient = taxChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
    taxClient.SetAppWebUrl(appWebUrl.ToString());
    if (!taxClient.IsInstalled())
        taxClient.Install();
    string logs = taxClient.GetLogs();

    ((ICommunicationObject)taxClient).Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (taxClient != null)
    {
        ((ICommunicationObject)taxClient).Abort();
    }
}
```

ISetupService:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISetupService
{
    string OpenText { get; }
    string DoneText { get; }
    string AppWebUrl { get; set; }

    [OperationContract]
    bool IsInstalled();

    [OperationContract]
    void SetLogComponent(LogList logList);

    [OperationContract]
    void SetAppWebUrl(string url);

    [OperationContract]
    void WriteToLog(string message);

    [OperationContract]
    string GetLogs();

    [OperationContract]
    void Install();        
}
```

My solution doesn't have to follow this approach though so I am looking for something better. Specifically, I need to pass a ClientContext object into my ISetupService constructor. What would be the simplest approach here?

Comment: Can you be more specific of what you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am looking for something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623432/how-to-pass-multiple-parameter-in-wcf-restful-service, only that I want to pass my parameter to my constructor, not a method.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 - Lazy Injectable property**
Why in the constructor? Why not have a Lazy Injectable property?

```
internal IClientContext Context 
{
    get { return _Context ?? (_Context = SomeStaticHelper.Context); }
    set { _Context = value; } // Allows for replacing IContext for unit tests
} private IClientContext _Context;

public class SomeStaticHelper
{
    public static IContext Context { get; set; } // Set this in global.asax
}
```

- Pro: No additional library
- Pro: Your can replace IContext in Unit Tests easily (use InternalsVisibleTo)
- Con: Class is coupled to SomeStaticHelper for compile.
- Con: Doing this for one class is nice, but doing this for 100 classes is not so nice.

**Option 2 - Dependency Injection**
Or you could use straight up dependency injection, such as Autofac.
http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/getting-started/

- Pro: The class is decoupled and the dependency is injected.
- Pro: If you have many classes that need dependency injection, this is the way to go because the overhead is now a couple class files instead of a property in every class file.
- Con: You have to add a framework to your code.
- Con: You now need more code and other objects to configure the dependency injection.

Use option 1 for small projects that have little need for dependency injection. I think this is the simplest approach here.

Use option 2 for large projects that use DI all the time.

Comment: I will try this when I get back to work on monday and provide feedback. Gave up and went home a broken man. :)