# Using Select2 with AJAX and JSON and WCF service

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, wcf, jquery-select2

I have an issue with Select2 tool as i'm trying to send more than a parameter to the tool and retrieve list of objects however i'm not able to use any; 
Thank you all for your time.
My Ajax code is as below:

```
$('.autoComplete').select2({
      placeholder: 'Test',
      width: '200px',
      //width: 'resolve',//Doesn't work also
      quietMillis: 100,
      minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
      selectOnClose: true,
      minimumInputLength: 0,
      allowClear: true,
      ajax: {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: 'http://localhost/Srvc.svc/Test',
        data: function(term) {
          return {
            custName: term
          }
        },
        processResults: function(data, params) {
          var count = 0;
          var obj = {};
          obj = $.map(data, function(item) {
            $.each(item, function(k, custObj) {
              //Hint: The alert part works so i kept it as one of tray out
              //alert(custObj.CustID + ', ' + custObj.CustName);
              obj[count] = {
                id: custObj.id,
                text: custObj.text
              };
              count += 1;
            });
          });
          return obj;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean with `i'm trying to send more than a parameter to the tool`?

Comment: Sorry to the Service

Comment: I have used below code for sent data and worked successfully:  
`data: function (params) {
                        return JSON.stringify({
                            custName: params.term
                        });
                    },`
   The problem now is with the list sent by the service to the tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Data part i have used JSON.stringify and rename parameters into your same WCF parameters as names in javascript part:

```
    function (params) {
    return JSON.stringify({
    srch: params.term
    });
    }
```

And for the part of results:
Edit WCF service to send List of object as {id, text} as select2 tool format is waiting for then WCF enclosed results under d parameter so we should select it from returned data:

```
    processResults: function (data) {
    return { results: data.d };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to attach multiple parameters to your `url` like this

```
...
url: 'http://localhost/Srvc.svc/parameter1/parameter2/parameter3',
...
```

This link maybe helps you too: 
[How to pass multiple parameter in wcf restful service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623432/how-to-pass-multiple-parameter-in-wcf-restful-service)

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, currently my problem with the return only 
I have tried Successfully
`data: function (params) {
                        return JSON.stringify({
                            custName: params.term
                        });
                    }`